# Replace entire string by one specific word

Tags: r, string-substitution

I have this column in a df:

| Column1 |
| --- |
| very sunny day today |
| it was sunny |
| not very sunny today |

desired output

| Column1 |
| --- |
| sunny |
| sunny |
| not sunny |

```
df<-df%>%
  mutate(column_1=case_when(
    str_detect(column_1,"very sunny")~ "sunny",
    str_detect(column_1,"sunny")~ "sunny",
    str_detect(column_1,"not"&"sunny")~ " not sunny",
  )
         )
```

The code works well for the two first rows where we have more simple conditions for the 3rd row the conditions are more complicated and gives me an error.

I want to identify some keywords in that string which they are not together (very sunny) but they are separate (not very sunny today) and put them as conditions to give the desired output. Maybe I am doing something wrong with syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Would it be && instead of & in the 3rd row

Comment: thanks for the comment but i still get an error: x invalid 'x type in 'x && y'

Comment: I think if you split the third statement into two it might work...but as the second statement will return true, the case_when will complete before it gets there

Comment: In your simple case, you only need to identify the word "not", in which case, instead of the `case_when()`, use an `ifelse()` statement `df %>% 
  mutate(column_1 = ifelse(str_detect(column_1, "not") == TRUE, "not sunny", "sunny"))`  Though, this becomes complicated if there are more negative words.

Comment: thank you for the comment and the help. I have more rows in my actual dataset, for example, the value 'not very rainy today and the desired output I would like to be 'not rainy', so in this case, it's more complicated because there are two keywords. The code I posted workers fine except the last line. The operator  '&' results in an error and I don't know why. @TechCommodities

Answer (score 0):

```
df$column2 <- sub('(not )?.*(sunny).*', '\\1\\2', df$Column1)
df
               Column1   column2
1 very sunny day today     sunny
2         it was sunny     sunny
3 not very sunny today not sunny
```

Comment: Mr. Onyambu, I didn't know if we don't specify a back reference like `\\2`  all matches for the second captured group will be replaced by "". It's very interesting.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
df <- data.frame(column_1 = c("very sunny today", "sunny today", "not very sunny today", "very very sunny today", "sunny today, not", "not sunny today", "no sun today"))

df%>%
  mutate(column_1 = case_when(
    (str_detect(column_1,"not") & str_detect(column_1,"sunny")) ~ "not sunny",
    str_detect(column_1,"very sunny")~ "sunny",
    str_detect(column_1,"sunny")~ "sunny",
    TRUE ~ "Unspecified"
  )
)
```

It copes with the *not* coming before or after the *sunny*, and separated by zero or more words.  I added a few more examples to your test dataframe. It's good practice to include the `TRUE ~ ""` statement to `case_when()`, unless you're sure all possible inputs will be captured.